# One Availability group, two primary nodes

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I have two nodes A & B, I'm trying to set Node A to be primary for DB1 with Node B as its secondary and then set up Node B as primary for DB2 and Node A as its secondary. (I'm using SQL 14.0.1000.169)

[image]

Do I need two Availability groups, two listeners, two failover clusters?
Currently I have one of each.

I was able to successfully create the Availability group for the first scenario but now I'm lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) mentioned:

You need one Windows Server Failover Cluster (WSFC) with both server member of the WSFC.

You need AG1 (Availability Group) and Listener1. DB1 will go in this Availability Group.

You need AG2 (Availability Group) and Listener2. DB2 will go in this Availability Group.

Now you have the option of having both database primary in one server or each database primary on separate server.

You should also upgrade from RTM. There will be no service packs for SQL 2017, and so CUs aren't really optional.  You don't have to install every one, but you need to have a regular schedule of applying them, and for a new solution you should always start with the latest CU. See [Announcing the Modern Servicing Model for SQL Server.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/announcing-the-modern-servicing-model-for-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

I think your question was answered already, but one important point wasn't mentioned.  If you are only running one secondary replica and your secondary is always passive, then you don't have to license it, but if you run primary databases on both nodes, then they must both be fully licensed.